# _.bindAll() on JavaScript singleton methods?

Tags: javascript, binding, underscore.js

The method obj2.method1, in the code below, is called from another object.
How do I bind the "this context" so that I can refer to obj1 from obj2?

```
var singleton = {
  obj1 : {
     a : 5
  },

  obj2 : {
    method1 : function(){
       this.obj1.a; //undefined
    }
  }
}
```

I tried using underscore _.bindAll() - something along these lines - but failed ...

```
var singleton = {
  obj1 : {
     a : 5
  },

  obj2 : {
    method1 : function(){
       this.obj1.a; //undefined
    }
  },
  init : function(){
       _.bind(this, obj2.method1)
  }
}

singleton.init();
```

Thanks :)

Comment: `singleton.obj1.a` would work...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Hmm, but I think the other object calls the method using apply. Which I want to override ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to *reassign* `singleton.obj2.method2()` with the results of `_.bind()`:

   // in .init():

   this.obj2.method1 = _.bind(this.obj2.method1, this)
2. To have `singleton.init()` have a proper `this` when called, you need to specify it explicitly:

   singleton.init.call(singleton)

Full demonstration [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jacob414/GmbWU/). But remember, the `Singleton` pattern [is](https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/singleton-considered-stupid) [bad](http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/07/03/pattern-hate-singleton/), [m'kay](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx)?

Comment: That's a great answer. Thanks :) By the way - instead of the singleton pattern, what would you recommend in this case where I'm trying to come up with a simple "helper utility". The utility should store a bunch of application settings (some of which need to be initialized on init()) which it can reference in its different helper methods. I thought a singleton would be OK as other application objects can then ask this helper to perform some common calculations based on both given arguments and settings? Thanks again.